# Unauthorize / Unlink the own iOS App in GoogleDrive SDK

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I'm trying to find a way to unauthorize / unlink / disconnect my iOS App from the users GoogleDrive account.

Google exactly describes in their [references and tutorials](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/) how to authorize the App but not the other way around. I already tried something like:

```
[_serviceDrive.authorizer stopAuthorization];
NSLog(@"%d", self.isAuthorized);
```

but NSLog is still returning "1", so it's still authorized and I still can see my App on Google's [Connected Apps](https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps) website.

Does anybody know how to disconnect it?

Answer (score 0):

You can [remove Google Drive apps](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2500820?hl=en&rd=1) by revoking its permission. You can do this by following this steps:

1. Go to [accounts.google.com](https://myaccount.google.com/).
2. Click Connected apps & sites.
3. Click Manage apps.
4. Click an app you want to remove.
5. Click Remove.
6. Click OK.

Another way is by [revoking the access of a token in application](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#revoking-access-to-a-token-or-application).

- For applications that create app activities, users can revoke actions using the App Settings page.
- For all applications, including those that write app activities, a user can revoke authorization by following the "Websites authorized to access the account" link from the [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard). Users can go directly to the authorization manager at [https://accounts.google.com/issuedauthsubtokens and revoke access](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions).